# python list contains hexadecimal values

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to find the uncommon lines from both the file.

If I do  "print line" I get the lines, whereas if I try to push each line to list                               "diff_list" it stores in hexademical. 
      please let me know how to write lines into list and when i print it out, i should get   the lines rather than hexadecimal values

```
    ['\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x0
     0 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x0
     0 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00}\x00\r\x00', '\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00
    \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00}\x00\r\x00', '\x00 \x00
    \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00
   \x00}\x00\r\x00', '\x00F\x00u\x00l\x00l\x00C\x00r\x00a\x00w\x00l\x00L\x00i\x00s\
    x00t\x00 \x00=\x00 \x00{\x00 \x00\r\x00', '\x00A\x00l\x00w\x00a\x00y\x00s\x00A\x
    00u\x00t\x00h\x00L\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00 \x00=\x00 \x00{\x00 \x00\r\x00', '\x00 \x0
    0 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x0
    0 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00}\x00\r\x00', '\x00P\x00r\x00o\x00t\x00
    e\x00c\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00R\x00u\x00l\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00=\x00 \x00{\x00 \x00
    \r\x00', '\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00
   \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00}\x00\r\x00', '\x00M\x00a\
x00n\x00g\x00l\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00B\x00y\x00p\x00a\x00s\x00s\x00L\x00i\x00s\x00t\
x00 \x00=\x00 \x00{\x00 \x00\r\x00']
```

below is my code :

```
  file1 = set(line.strip() for line in open(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\abc.txt'))
  file2 = set(line.strip() for line in pen(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\abc1.txt'))
  diff_list=[]
  for line in file1:

         if line not in (file1 & file2):

             diff_list.append(line.strip())

 print diff_list
```

Comment: This link https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html provides details about sets in python. you can find uncommon lines easily using set operations

Answer (score 2):

Use `file1.symmetric_difference(file2)`to get a new set with elements in either `file1` or `file2` but not both.

Using [set.symmetric_difference(t)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects), you can pass any iterable so you don't need to create a second set.

Answer (score 1):

In python, Set implements useful functions for Set theory such as union, difference and disjunction, The below code calculate the uncommon lines

```
uncommon_lines = file1.union(file2) - (file1 & file2)
```